# Destructuring/Unpacking first and rest in Clojure

Tags: python-3.x, clojure, iterable-unpacking

In Python 3, if you want to unpack the first and rest of a list (or tuple), you do

```
x, *y = [1, 2, 3]
#x = 1, y = [2, 3]
```

How do you do this inside a let block in Clojure? I've tried `:as parts` and

```
(defn destructurer [vec]
  (let [[beginning the-rest :as parts] vec]
    [beginning the-rest]
    )
  )
;; (destructer [1 2 3])
;; [1 2] <- missing the 3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add an `&` to make the next binding capture `rest`:

```
(defn destructurer [vec]
  (let [[beginning & the-rest :as parts] vec]
    [beginning the-rest]
    )
  )
```

There's a nice `github` gist on clojure destructuring capabilities [here](https://gist.github.com/john2x/e1dca953548bfdfb9844).